# Cisco VPN - no VPN connection was active

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, vpnc

perhaps you will be able to help me.
My machine is running Ubuntu 14.04 64bit
I've created new Cisco VPN profile, put gateway, my username, password and when trying to connect it gives me an error:

[VPN connection failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK8m4.png)

Output from logs:

```
Oct 16 18:12:57 HP-Workstation NetworkManager[801]:  Starting VPN service 'vpnc'...
Oct 16 18:12:57 HP-Workstation NetworkManager[801]:  VPN service 'vpnc' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.vpnc), PID 3136
Oct 16 18:12:57 HP-Workstation NetworkManager[801]:  VPN service 'vpnc' appeared; activating connections
Oct 16 18:12:57 HP-Workstation NetworkManager[801]:  VPN plugin state changed: starting (3)
Oct 16 18:12:57 HP-Workstation NetworkManager[801]:  VPN connection 'IT Academy' (Connect) reply received.
Oct 16 18:12:57 HP-Workstation NetworkManager[801]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Oct 16 18:12:57 HP-Workstation NetworkManager[801]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Oct 16 18:12:57 HP-Workstation NetworkManager[801]:  /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Oct 16 18:12:57 HP-Workstation ModemManager[652]:   Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: access technology changed (umts -> hsupa)
Oct 16 18:12:58 HP-Workstation ModemManager[652]:   Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: access technology changed (hsupa -> hspa)
Oct 16 18:12:58 HP-Workstation ModemManager[652]:   Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: signal quality updated (77)
Oct 16 18:12:58 HP-Workstation NetworkManager[801]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Oct 16 18:12:58 HP-Workstation NetworkManager[801]:  VPN plugin failed: 1
Oct 16 18:12:58 HP-Workstation NetworkManager[801]:  VPN plugin state changed: stopped (6)
Oct 16 18:12:58 HP-Workstation NetworkManager[801]:  VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Oct 16 18:12:58 HP-Workstation NetworkManager[801]:  Policy set 'Play Online Default' (ppp0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Oct 16 18:12:58 HP-Workstation NetworkManager[801]:  error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Oct 16 18:13:01 HP-Workstation ModemManager[652]:   Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: signal quality updated (90)
```

Any idea what may case this issue?